# PHP: Create button for popup window to display contents of text file

Tags: php, html

I have a Php application that already has 2 buttons with input on the index page that perform some functions and output to different Php pages. Works good. How do I add a button with no input that would just perform a function and then just display a popup window showing the contents of a text file? I want to add several of these buttons for different functions and just display the contents of the resulting text files in popup windows. If it's a simple HTML solution forgive me for labeling it as PHP. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First check [popup window script](http://www.textfixer.com/html/javascript-pop-up-window.php). In popup URL add your parameters...

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define a click function for the required button and need to call `window.open()`. Check out this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4m0vfv20/2/)**

More on [window.open()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)